# input expected at most 1 argument, got 2 python

Tags: python

I keep receiving this error (TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument, got 2) and I can't figure out why. The goal of the code is to keep asking for a number until that number is between one and a variable called n.

```
def enterValidNumber(n):
     while True:
         num = int(input("Input a number from 1 to", n)) 
         if num >= 1 and num <= n:
             break

enterValidNumber(17)
```

Comment: I just realised it has to do with the fact that I added n to the input which isnt allowed. What is another way I could write this code without doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right; you are giving two parameters to `input`. To put `n` into the prompt string, you can use an f-string:

```py
num = int(input(f"Input a number from 1 to {n}"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always go with j1-lee's answer but I would have another suggestion:

```
num = int(input("Input a number from 1 to " + str(n)))
```

this would work well too!

Comment: Or simply `num = int(input("Input a number from 1 to %d" % n))`